# NHibernate Illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am stuck from about 12 hours with this error so could any one help me at least to understand what is wrong

Here is my code

```
public virtual void AssignAssets(IList<long?> assetsIds, ManualAssetAssignment<TAsset>.AssignmentMode mode, IQueryableRepository<TAsset, long?> assetRepository)
{
    this.Assets.Clear();
    if (mode == AssignmentMode.Execlusion)
    {
        //IList<long?> includedAssetsIds = assetRepository.Find().Where(entity => !assetsIds.Contains(entity.Id)).Select(entity => entity.Id).ToList();
        IList<TAsset> includedAssets = assetRepository.Find().Where(entity => !assetsIds.Contains(entity.Id)).ToList();
        foreach (var asset in includedAssets)
        {
            this.Assets.Add(asset);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var assetId in assetsIds)
        {
            var asset = assetRepository.Get(assetId);
            this.Assets.Add(asset);
        }
    }
    _areAssetsEvaluated = true;
}
```

Here is my test

```
using (var tx = DataSessionContext.Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    atm = new Atm(AtmTestData.AutoCompleteCommand(new Atm.SetupCommand() { }), commandDependencyRegistry);
    atmRepository.Save(atm);
    List<long?> atmIds = new List<long?> { atm.Id };

    var command = AtmExpenseTestData.AutoCompleteCommand(new AssetExpense<Atm>.SetupCommand());
    expense = new AssetExpense<Atm>
    (
        command, commandDependencyRegistry
    );

    var assignCommand1 = new AssetExpense<Atm>.ManualAssetAssignmentCommand()
    {
        AssetsIds = new List<long?>() { atm.Id.Value },
        Mode = ManualAssetAssignment<Atm>.AssignmentMode.Execlusion
    };
    assignCommand1.Execute(expense, commandDependencyRegistry);
    atmAssetExpenseRepository.Save(expense);

    tx.Commit();
}
```

the weird thing is that if I replace this piece in my code

```
IList<TAsset> includedAssets = assetRepository.Find().Where(entity => !assetsIds.Contains(entity.Id)).ToList();
foreach (var asset in includedAssets)
{
    this.Assets.Add(asset);
}
```

By this

```
IList<long?> includedAssetsIds = assetRepository.Find().Where(entity => !assetsIds.Contains(entity.Id)).Select(entity => entity.Id).ToList();
foreach (var assetId in includedAssetsIds)
{
    this.Assets.Add(assetRepository.Get(assetId));
}
```

If I replace it the error disappear so could anyone help me to understand this error.

**Edit - This might be helpful**

From Stack Trace I get that the exception be thrown from this method specifically on line 13 `return (TId)((ISession)Session).Save(entity);`

```
public virtual TId Save(TAggregateRoot entity, Action commitPostAction, Action rollbackPostAction, bool propagatePostActionError = false)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
    }

    if (entity is IValidatable)
    {
        ((IValidatable)entity).Validate();
    }
    RegisterPostActions(commitPostAction, rollbackPostAction, propagatePostActionError);
    if (Session is ISession)
    {
        return (TId)((ISession)Session).Save(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        return (TId)((IStatelessSession)Session).Insert(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: how exactly are you creating the session?

Answer (score 1):

Lists(`IList`, `ISet`...) and References from Entities are Proxies in NHibernate. This allows you to lazy load them. The exception tells you that you are using one of this proxies in two open sessions. That means you are loading a entity in one session and try to save it in another. If this is intended, close the first session before you use the next one. I would recommend to use the UnitOfWork Pattern to prevent such behaviour.

Comment: I made sure different times that the session has the same session Id is the same using DataSessionContext.Session

Comment: Unfortunately NHibernate has another opinion^^ You can try [NHibernate Profiler](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) to check the open sessions. Its free for 30 days and imho a essential tool for each developer that works with NHibernate.

Comment: The Url seems currently down, but it worked 5 minutes ago. Just try again later if it didn't work for you. And please let us know if you could resolve your problem ;)

Comment: the issue caused because we were trying to make Quryable sessions as read only session which it was creating a sub session and that what was causing the problem, the solution either by reverting it to be normal session or by using Evict as a cascade rule.